# When are free products of pairs of groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-product

Suppose that $G_1$, $G_2$, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are non-trivial groups. Under what conditions do we have $$G_1 \ast H_1 \cong G_2 \ast H_2?$$

Is it the case that if $G_1 \cong G_2$ then we only have such an isomorphism if $H_1 \cong H_2$?

This may be quite a wide and complicated question, so if a full answer is difficult, I'm most interested in the following two cases:

1) $G_1 \cong G_2$ and $H_1$, $H_2$ are both finite.

2) $G_1 \cong G_2$ and $H_1$, $H_2$ are both free.

Comment: You might want to restrict attention to finitely generated groups, since otherwise it's easy to construct examples in which $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not isomorphic. Let $G_1$ be a free product of infinitely many copies of $H_1$ and of $H_2$.

Comment: Ah, of course. So for example, if $G_1 \cong G_2 \cong F_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $H_1 \cong F_3$, $H_2 \cong F_5$, then $G_1 \ast H_1 \cong G_2 \ast H_2 \cong F_{\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic words are [Grushko decomposition Theorem.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Grushko_theorem)

Comment: @user60589 The link provides a complete answer to your question. If you don't want it, suit yourself.